# A way to add newLine in my transition text

Tags: jquery, html

I search about over 1 hour now and dont find any way to bring a new Line to my text after every sentence. Maybe u have some advice for me how this in my speacialy Project can work :)
I want to add a line break every time in my text(u will see) is a \n tag.

i tried it with html(text).text() but it wont happens anything.
the most solutions i found worked not for me :( (maybe i insert it wrong)

```css
#navbar-header a {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar-header {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-item {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}

.navbar {
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

footer {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

#welcomeHead{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 300px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round';
    font-size: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3rem;
    letter-spacing: .8rem;
    color: #000000;
}
#welcomeBody span{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3rem;
    color: #000000 !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="bootstrap-overrides">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbar-header">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Aufgaben
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="test" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML Brief</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erste Website</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tabellen</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JavaScript</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Raster Layout</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bericht</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase" id="welcomeHead">Willkommen auf meiner Seite</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#welcomeHead").hover(function () {
                $("#welcomeHead").fadeOut(function () {
                    $("#welcomeHead").css({"padding-top": "200px", "font-size": "1.5rem", "letter-spacing": "0rem"});
                $(this).text("Auf dieser Seite wird ihnen mein Portfolio, mit allen bisher erfüllten Aufgaben bereigestellt. Diese finden sie unter dem Punkt Aufgaben.\n Unter Bericht steht ihnen der gesamte Werdegang dieser Seite anschaulich zur Verfügung.\nInfos zu meiner Person und meinem persöhnlichen Werdegang finden sie unter About. \nFalls es nach dies allem noch Fragen, Wünsche oder Anmerkungen gibt können sie mich unter Kontakt jederzeit per Mail kontaktieren.\n Viel Spaß auf meiner Seite.")
            }).fadeIn();
        }, function () {
            $("#welcomeHead").fadeOut(function () {
                $("#welcomeHead").css({"padding-top": "300px", "font-size": "3rem", "letter-spacing": "0.8rem"});
                $(this).text("Willkommen auf meiner Seite")
            }).fadeIn();
        }
        );
        });
    </script>
    <footer class="page-footer font-small cyan darken-3 fixed-bottom">
        <!-- Quelle:https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/ -->
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
            <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="25" height="25" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
            © 2019 Copyright: Marvin Damnik
            <a href="#">Impressum</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery `html()` instead of `text()`, you can add in HTML code and it will be interpreted as such. Then replace your `/n` line breaks with HTML line breaks `<br />`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#welcomeHead").hover(function() {
    $("#welcomeHead").fadeOut(function() {
      $("#welcomeHead").css({
        "padding-top": "200px",
        "font-size": "1.5rem",
        "letter-spacing": "0rem"
      });
      $(this).html("Auf dieser Seite wird ihnen mein Portfolio, mit allen bisher erfüllten Aufgaben bereigestellt<br /> Diese finden sie unter dem Punkt Aufgaben.<br /> Unter Bericht steht ihnen der gesamte Werdegang dieser Seite anschaulich zur Verfügung.<br />Infos zu meiner Person und meinem persöhnlichen Werdegang finden sie unter About. <br />Falls es nach dies allem noch Fragen, Wünsche oder Anmerkungen gibt können sie mich unter Kontakt jederzeit per Mail kontaktieren.<br /> Viel Spaß auf meiner Seite.")
    }).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $("#welcomeHead").fadeOut(function() {
      $("#welcomeHead").css({
        "padding-top": "300px",
        "font-size": "3rem",
        "letter-spacing": "0.8rem"
      });
      $(this).text("Willkommen auf meiner Seite")
    }).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar-header a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar-header {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.navbar {
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

footer {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

#welcomeHead {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: .8rem;
  color: #000000;
}

#welcomeBody span {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 200px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3rem;
  color: #000000 !important;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body id="bootstrap-overrides">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbar-header">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Aufgaben
                    </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="test" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML Brief</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erste Website</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tabellen</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JavaScript</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Raster Layout</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bericht</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase" id="welcomeHead">Willkommen auf meiner Seite</div>

  <footer class="page-footer font-small cyan darken-3 fixed-bottom">
    <!-- Quelle:https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/ -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
      <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="25" height="25" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo"> © 2019 Copyright: Marvin Damnik
      <a href="#">Impressum</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: wow that worked perfect thank you. my try look simmilar but i must be had a little mistake so it wont work ^^ 
can u give me another hint maybe so i do not ask a new question: how can i "disable" this animation and interaction while im in my navbar dropdown menu. sometimes i cant controll the dropdown cause the text change like crazy

Answer (score 0):

As @MichaelvE said, you can use `<br/>` for line breaks. [Check this link, it's a good reference](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/html-line-break)